# Searching a best practice to register users in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, registration, couchdb-2.0

Coming from a more traditional web frameworks like Django and a little bit Rails, I am a bit confused about what is the best to register new user in your couchdb backed web app. The registration process should include sending an e-mail with an activation link.

Can this be handled in couchdb completely? Or do I just write a little bit of code in my web app layer as I did before?

Any link or short explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB has a basic authentication system that allows you to create users, manager their roles and permissions.

Although, you'll probably need to add a certain logic in your application layer to support some of the basic feature of an authentication system.

For example, you would have to add some code to support password recovery.

Also, it supports Cookie authentication but you can't revoke cookies from a user(If that's an issue for you, don't use CouchDB's auth system)

Comment: FWIW, I think you can revoke cookies if you alter a users password. Perhaps you could change it then change it back to revoke a cookie without changing the password.